# Analysing multiple files using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have 10 files which I need to work on.
I need to import those files using pd.read_csv to turn them all into dataframes along with usecols as I only need the same two specific columns from each file.

I then need to search the two columns for a specific entry in the rows like ‘abcd’ and for python to return a new df with includes all the rows it appeared in for each file.

Is there a way I could do this using a for loop. For far I’ve only got a list of all the paths to the 10 files.

So far what I do for one file without the for loop is:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'filepath', header=2, usecols=['Column1', 'Column2'])

search_df = df.loc[df['Column1'] == 'abcd']
```

Comment: do you know the snytax of a for loop?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried so far.